# Vulnerabilities when setting up Firebase and React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, npm-package

I am trying to build an app using Firebase and React.
I have already done that in the past, but this time I hit some new issues.

Here are the commands I first run in the terminal:

```
% npx create-react-app vvhh
% cd vvhh
% npm install firebase
```

At this point I see this in the console:

```
added 69 packages, and audited 1553 packages in 9s

234 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Then I run this command:

```
% npm audit
```

And this is the result:

```
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

What is the best thing to do in this situation ?

I presume from previous experience that running:

```
% npm audit fix --force
```

would only bring trouble.

In case this may be useful, these are the versions I am using:

```
  % node --version
  v16.17.1
  % npm --version     
  8.15.0
  % firebase --version
  11.20.0
```